# Join multiple foreign keys with a single key in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables in my database. `Advertisement` and `AdLogo`.

`Advertisement` table has three logos. `OwnLogo`, `PublisherLogo` and `AggregatorLogo`

`AdLogo` table all the log information. ie, `LogoDisplayName`, `LogoPath` and `LogoType`. `LogoType` is an enum which will be  like this

```
enum LogoType {
    Own,
    Publisher,
    Aggregator
}
```

(Meant to convey that logo type will be one among these three in DB)

Now I want to perform a `linq-to-sql` join and map it into a ViewModel. How can I do this?

I am trying something like,

```
join adLogo in _context.AdvertisementLogos
on new { A = ad.OwnLogoId, B = ad.PublisherLogoId, C = ad.AggregatorLogoId }
equals new { A = adLogo.AdvertisementLogoId, B = adLogo.AdvertisementLogoId, C = adLogo.AdvertisementLogoId }
select new AdvertisementViewModel{
    Advertisement = ad,
    OwnLogo = "",
    PublisherLogo = "",
    AggregatorLogo = ""
};
```

which obviously doesn't work. I am clueless on the select statement.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: You  have to do three separate joins, right?  One for each column in Advertisement.

Comment: You need to make 3 joins with the same table.

Comment: Instead of doing joins looks into using the navigation properties that should exist in your model.  https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: oh ok. @juharr: its not possible here. long story :(